# cv::viz::Viz3d crashes when using with pcl_ros in ros noetic

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

When using point cloud library (pcl_ros) with opencv, cv::viz::Viz3d crashes.

It compiles normally, but when the node is executed it breaks on the line:

```
cv::viz::Viz3d viewer;
```

The cmakelists.txt file:

```
...   
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  pcl_ros # cv::viz::Viz3d does not work
)
...
```

```
...   
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  #pcl_ros # cv::viz::Viz3d, it works but I can not use pcl_ros 
)
...
```